# How to pass echo statements from an invoked shell script into the parameter of a method in the caller script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have 2 shell scripts. `script_1.sh` and `script_2.sh` and both have executable rights.

I have a method in `script_1.sh` to log the echo statements into a log file.

Following is `script_1.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
log() {
    /bin/echo $1 >> /path/to/theLogFile
}

TEST_VALUE=10
log "Logging a test value which says $TEST_VALUE"

# Calling script_2
/path/to/script_2
```

Following is `script_2.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "This is logging from script 2"
```

**Question:**
Everything that is `echo`ed from `script_1.sh` does get an entry into `theLogFile`. But obviously nothing from `script_2.sh`. My question is how can I call script_2 from `script_2.sh` so as to add all `echo` statements from `script_2.sh` get added into `theLogFile` as well **using the method `log` from script_1**.
Should I do something like this?

```
log(/path/to/script_2)
```

Or is there a better way?

Comment: How's `echo` in second script supposed to invoke `log` function?

Comment: `echo` in second script should not call `log` function. But I was thinking there should be a way to call `script_2` in such a way that the echo statements made in `script_2` are returned to `script_1`? Like we do it for `echo` itself? And then `script_1` can pass the returned echos from `script_2` into `log`? Ah, its tough to explain this in english

Comment: Sort of redirect the output of `script_2` into the `log` method?

Comment: I'd like to see an example of how you are _currently_ using your log function?

Comment: I updated `script_1` in my question showing an example usage of `log` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the stdout from script2 to be handled by log function then use `script1.sh` as this in `bash`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

logit() {
    command echo "$@" >> theLogFile
}
# export function definition
declare -fx logit

# Calling script_2 and redirect all stdout to logit function
(exec > >(logit "$(cat)"; exit); ./script2.sh)

# this will still be on stdout
echo "foo bar"
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Question: Does this mean that anything logged by any script into `stdout` will go into the `theLogFile`? Or is it that anything logged into `stdout` by `script1.sh` and `script2.sh` will go into `theLogFile`?

Comment: Only stdout of `script2` will go to `theLogFile`. As you can see last `echo` line in `scrip1` still going to normal terminal.

Comment: Oh great. In `script1.sh`, if I replace `echo "foo bar"` with `logit "foo bar"`, that should also work I think?

Comment: Yes of course if you call `logit` from any of the 2 scripts then it will go to `theLogFile`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative:

> script_1.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

exec >> theLogFile # redirect all stdout (I recommend stderr too... just add 2>&1)

TEST_VALUE=10
echo "Logging a test value which says $TEST_VALUE"

# Calling script_2
. script_2.sh      # source the second script so it runs with the same env
```

> script_2.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "This is logging from script 2"
```

> the output:

```
Logging a test value which says 10
This is logging from script 2
```

---

#### Alternate `script_1.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

log() { echo "$@"; } >> theLogFile

TEST_VALUE=10
log "Logging a test value which says $TEST_VALUE"

# Calling script_2
log "$(script_2.sh)" # pass ALL the output as a single formatted string
```